# Rank of matrix verification using row echelon form

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

[![][1]][1]

so in the sum we have to find the rank of matrix using echleon form.i have solved the sum and got rank of matrix 3.but the book from which i am solving the sum is showing rank 2.There are also few sums in the book where its the same situation. I just want to know whether the rank is 3 or 2 of this sum and if i am wrong then need hints to find rank 2
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFBpx.jpg

Comment: Please learn MathJax and post actual text, not pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you keep referring to the *sum*. The matrix you have does have rank $3$.